# Error while configuring TFS2010

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I am doing some work with TFS2010 and I've been trying to install it on a Windows 7 machine. I had it installed and then uninstalled it so I could change the SQLExpress to a SQL 2008 db. I rebooted between these changes just to be safe. The install went fine but when I tried to configure TFS2010 I get this error:

[ System Checks ] TF255510: The following path contains an access control list (ACL) that is not canonically ordered: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Application Tier\Web Access. This indicates that at least one file system permission required for installation is not configured correctly. You must resolve this issue before Team Foundation Server can be successfully installed. It might be possible to resolve this error by changing the properties for file or directory security in Windows Explorer. For more information, see this page on the Microsoft Web site: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=184320.

The link is broken so that didn't help. I'm not sure what the whole "canonically ordered" thing is about and searched around for some explainations but nothing really helped the problem.

The log showed some other errors that don't mean much to me either:

[Error  @19:53:05.351] System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800706D9): Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {304CE942-6E39-40D8-943A-B913C40C9CD4} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 800706d9.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.Firewall..ctor()
[Error  @19:53:05.351] Verify Threw: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800706D9): Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {304CE942-6E39-40D8-943A-B913C40C9CD4} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 800706d9.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.Firewall..ctor()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.VerifyFirewallInstalled.Verify()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.VerifyNode.Verify():

Has anyone seen this error or have any idea how to solve it? Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. I installed TFS2010 on a second Windows 7 machine and configured it the same way and it worked fine. Maybe there's some things left in the registery or something. Not sure.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:  http://theachabsolutions.blogspot.com/2011/03/errore-tf255510-in-fase-di.html

Translated into English:

Here are the security settings to be set for all folders in TFS 2010 (C: \ Program Files \ Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010), which allow the resolution of the error TF255510

CREATOR OWNER: Full Control *
SYSTEM: Full Control
Administrators: Full Control
Users: Modify, Read & Execute, List Folder Contents
TrustedInstaller: List Folder Contents, Full Control *

Comment: Although this wasn't exactly what I needed to do, it got me in the right direction. I couldn't change any of the permissions on the Create Owner, but I modified the System removing the Special selection and that let TFS configure.